# Including css and javascript files in spring 4 project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm making a web app using Spring 4, the Spring security module and tomcat 8. I'm trying to include some css files and js files in a .jsp file, but it's not working. When I check in the sources tag in Chrome the content of the css seems to be a log in form. I suspect that it may have something to do with spring security.

My css file is included like this in the .jsp

```
<link href="<c:url value='resources/css/materialize.min.css' />" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css"></link>
```

This is the WebConfig file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypackage")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");  
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);  
        return resolver;  
    }
    @Autowired
    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new   HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

This is the SecurityConfig file

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/js/**", "/resources/css/**", "/resources/img/**", "/resources/font/**");
    }   
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/signin")
            .failureUrl("/signin?param.error=bad_credentials")
        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/signout")
        .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico", "/resources/css/**", "/resources/font/**",
                        "/resources/js/**", "/auth/**", "/signin/**", "/signup/**", "/disconnect/facebook").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and()
            .rememberMe().
        and().csrf();
    }
}
```

According to other answers here in stackoverflow it should work with the code that I have but the css only returns this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:social="http://spring.io/springsocial"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorator="layout">
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <title>Insert title here</title>
     </head>
     <body>
    <div id="content" >
        <form id="signin" action="signup" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="" value=""/>
            <div class="formInfo">

            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <label for="login">Email</label>
                <input id="login" name="email" type="text" size="25"></input>
                <label for="Nombre">Email</label>
                <input id="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" size="25"></input>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="password" name="contrasena" type="password" size="25"></input>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit">Sign In</button>


            <p>Or you can <a href="signin">signin</a> with a new account.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

All my css and js files are inside WebContent/resources

Comment: Not sure, but in your jsp file your css is include with a relative url. Did you try with an absolute url ? 

<c:url value='**/resources/css/materialize.min.css**' />"

Comment: @Elthum I tested it with the leading / but now it just returns an empty file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, apparently there was an ambiguous routing in one of my controllers, so when I tried to access a url that started with "/resources" it routed it to the controller, and thus returned a .jsp instead of the css/js/image. My original controller binded the url in the @Controller, and left the @RequestMapping without indicating the route.

```
@Controller("/signup")
public class SignUpController {
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signUpForm(){
        ...
    }
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String crearUsuario(HttpServletRequest request){
        ...
    }
```

So I changed the @Controller annotation, and put the url in each @RequestMapping like this:

```
@Controller
public class SignUpController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String signUpForm(){}
    @RequestMapping(value="/signup",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String crearUsuario(HttpServletRequest request){}
}
```